# How do I refresh an ExactTarget token using the REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, refresh-token

How do I refresh an ExactTarget token using the REST API?  Is there any good documentation on this?

Comment: You're using the /refreshToken route right, with the ClientID and ClientSecret?  And, you're trying to refresh when the previous token has expired?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the /refreshToken route.  It doesn't appear in the API documentation.  The API docs mention a refreshToken but not how to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would refresh your token the same way you got it initially using

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken Content-Type: application/json { "clientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FROM_APP_CENTER", "clientSecret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_APP_CENTER" } 200 OK { "accessToken": "dfy3dsnqw3gre6e3pbatcr4s" "expiresIn": 3600 }
```

If you are building an application for the HubExchange, you would add the refresh token. The route is documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm

Comment: My concern is that we cannot refresh the token within one hour of having received it.  Once the hour has elapsed the token is no longer good and we need a new one.  If we're in the process of making numerous requests using the token at the time the token expires, the requests will begin failing until we retrieve a new token.  In the span of one second we may have many requests fail.  Refreshing the token prior to expiration would be desirable.  I think you're telling me this isn't possible using the REST API, is that correct?

Comment: You want to add those scenarioa in your flow. Check if its about to expire, and then during the call if it fails, submit another auth call. Its doable.

Comment: Sounds great but may not be possible.  Please see my other question on this solution: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44749/unit-testing-callout-with-custom-setting

Comment: Not sure how to fit it into your current solution. Can you not store the current expiration time and check against that?

Comment: My other question was answered and the resolution was simple.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout `"accessType": "offline"` when request for access token. It will give you a refresh access token to use when the "main" access token has expire, this refresh token is valid up to 700 days and has a 5-minute revocation period after use. You will have an extra window of 5 min to continue making requests when the "main" token expire.

Hope this helps: [MC requestToken Referemce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm)